# How to reset the focus of the XAML designer?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, designer

So I right clicked the name of a `DataTemplate` in my XAML and selected "Go To Definition".  This changed the content of the designer from showing the page I was working on to showing the  `DataTemplate` defined in the page resources.

How do I switch the designer back to showing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can click the icon in the top left of the Document Outline window.
[image: Return scope to... icon]

Note: this is based on someone else's answer which was deleted before I could check it.